# Cpanel directory chgrp issues

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd

I'm struggling to get a directory to work with user:group.

After creating the directory via WHM I've logged in via SSH and set:

```
chgrp -R developers mysitedirectory
```

Which results in a 500 internal server error.

I've also added the Cpanel user for this website to the developers group using usermod:

```
usermod -a -G developers Cpanel_user
```

Any help to get this directory working with read & write permissions for everyone in the group would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

The directory is in /home and is generated when adding a new account to WHM / Cpanel

The directory contains website files, the site works fine when set to user:user but throws 500 error when using user:developers

User is also a part of developers

**EDIT 2**

Error log shows:

Premature end of script headers: index.php

SoftException in Application.cpp:422: Mismatch between target UID (99) and UID (502) of file “/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/index.php

folders are set to chmod 755 and files to chmod 644

Comment: Where is this directory? What's it's relationship to your site?  A subdirectory? Does it contain webpages? Who else needs to read it? What server are you using? What operating system are you using? The 500 error probably means that the directory also needs to be accessed by the apache (or whichever server you are using) user as well and that user is not a member of developers.

Comment: the web server error log will give you information about the what it was trying to do when it generated the 500 error. in addition to the info @terdon mentioned.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to respond. Which log file should i be looking in? /etc/httpd/logs/error_log ?

Comment: @Danny that is usually the one

Comment: Edited above to show error log entries.